# Python Time Perf_Counter() CONFUSION

Tags: python, time

So, really I'm just confused, I've been learning python, and I was given an exercise to find the performance speed of a function, however after finishing the code I received an error in the time output, it was 3.215000000000856e-06, this value varies with every time I run the program though so you probably won't get the same output.(in reality it was less then a second.) I went through the video where it explained how to write how they did it and changed a how I wrote a statement, now my code is Identical, to theirs but with different variable names, I ran the program and the same problem, however they didn't experience this issue, heres the code:

```
import time

SetContainer = {I for I in range(1002)}
ListContainer = [I for I in range(1002)]

def Search(Value, Container):

    if Value in Container:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Function_Speed(Func, HMT = 1, **arg):
    sum = 0

    for I in range(HMT):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        print (Func(**arg))
        end = time.perf_counter()
        sum = sum + (end - start)
    return (sum, )

print (Function_Speed(Search, Value = 402,
                      Container = SetContainer))
```

Possible Answers?:
Could it be my hardware? My version of Python is no longer supported(The video is over a year old I'm using 3.6) or it turns out I screwed up.

(Edit:) By the way it does work when the function is printed so this example works, but without `print (Func(**arg))` and instead `Func(**arg)` it doesn't work.

Comment: Could it have been a number in scientific notation?  The time taken by a single lookup in a set (which is particularly efficient for this kind of operation) is going to be very, very small.  (The actual output, rather than "something like", would have been helpful here.)  Note that you really don't want that `print()` inside the region of code being timed, that's likely to take longer than the actual code of interest.

Comment: I completely agree with the `print()` code being Undesirable , Thank you so much for the feedback, I'll make an edit to display the actual output. :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, your capitalization of variable and function violates convention.  Though not a syntax error, it makes it difficult for Python programmers to follow your code.

Second, the result you got makes sense.  A single iteration of the search on a modern computer takes very little time.  If your printed result was in the form `1.23456e-05`, then that is a valid number so small that the default representation shifted to scientific notation.

Add a value for `HMT`, starting with 100000, and see what is output.

Comment: I see, This works perfect, however i'm surprised by how fast the program runs, is there any way this is an error, my computer is a mac and at least six years old?

Comment: @CKPixel  The task that `Search()` performs against `SetContainer` is an efficient lookup, and I would expect a computer from twenty years ago to do this very quickly.  I suspect that you set out to see the difference between searching a `set` vs a `list`, so you may want to proceed with that test.